# Excel macro using Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint" with group selection of sheets

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am trying to create a macro that selects more than one worksheet and then presents the Excel print dialog that shows the print preview, thus enabling the user to choose their printer, number of copies etc.  So far I have the following:

```
Sub PrintReport()
'
' PrintReport Macro
'
'
    Sheets(Array("Cover page", "Scoresheet")).Select
    Sheets("Cover page").Activate
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"
   
End Sub
```

This is the only code I've found so far that displays the correct dialog box, but the two lines that make the group worksheet selection (created by Record Macro function) are not working, i.e. only one worksheet is being presented for printing.  I infer that the ExecuteMso function is probably clearing the selection during initialisation.  Can anyone suggest a way to get what I want?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior but you could try moving the `Sheets("Cover page").Activate` before  `Sheets(Array("Cover page", "Scoresheet")).Select`

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - unfortunately that made no difference.

Comment: I also can't recreate the behavior as described (i.e. your code behaves as expected and present the two sheets in 'normal' print preview). I can create that behavior if the 2nd sheet is blank (i.e. a clean empty sheet), but must assume that's not the case here. And all that suggests it's a version-related bug/issue.

Comment: Thank you @Spinner.  I am inclined to agree;  there have been several small behavioural changes recently that I assume are due to an update.  I think I'll just live with this for the time being and see if another update cures the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert and only new but I found this code that runs through all the sheets I selected in the `Plist` (list of sheets I want to be printed) puts them in an array then opens the print preview page ready for printing.

It may help?

```
Sub Print_sh()

'multiple sheet printing

Dim SHT As Long, RN As Long

Dim SHEETARRAY() As String

 Dim WP As Variant
 Dim I As Long
 
With ActiveSheet.PList

'(Plist is a list of sheets i want printed)

    For SHT = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(SHT) Then
            ReDim Preserve SHEETARRAY(RN)
            SHEETARRAY(RN) = .Column(1, SHT)
            RN = RN + 1
            End If
        Next SHT
    End With

    For Each WP In SHEETARRAY
        Sheets(WP).Activate
        

Sheets(SHEETARRAY()).PrintPreview
```

Good luck, I am sure there is a mistake somewhere, there are much smarter people that can help us make it better. It may get you started?

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get all this to work - I am clearly no expert myself - but I eventually settled for using the .PrintPreview option even though it doesn't present the full print preview dialog that I get by default with Ctrl/P (it uses what appears to be an older version).

Still interested to understand why the ExecuteMSO "PrintPreviewAndPrint" option loses the sheets group selection.